# Razor - compare time conditional

Tags: c#, razor

I want to show an element if it occurs on or after 5:00 PM.  How can I set up the conditional to do this?

```
<div class="time">@Model.EventDateAndTime</div> <!-- outputs JUN 18 2015 9:00 PM -->

@if(@Model.EventDateAndTime > ??? ){
     <a href="#">My Link</a>
}
```

Comment: Do you care about timezone?

Answer (score 4):

The `DateTime` structure [has an `Hour` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libraRy/system.datetime.hour.aspx):

```
@if(Model.EventDateAndTime.Hour >= 17){
    <a href="#">My Link</a>
}
```

Comment: does this work for the minutes for example  5:01 > 5:00

Comment: @DanHunex: The `Hour` component would still be `17` if the time is `5:01 PM`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @if(Model.OfferType == "TM Event" && DateTime.Parse(Model.EventDateAndTime).ToString("HH").AsInt() >= 17 ){
       <a href="https://www.sevenrooms.com/direct/reservation-request/musichalllv/table" data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="button upgrade" style="padding-top:25px;" data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="button table">VIP TABLE INQUIRY</a>
  }
```